# Проверка полей на заполненность при нажатии на ENTER

Tags: javascript, jquery

Совсем запуталась, подскажите.
Есть таблица. Реализована функция по добавлению к ней пустой строки, ячейки которой являются input-ами. При нажатии на ENTER нужно добавлять введенные (в ячейки) данные в таблицу (если все поля заполнены).
В Интернете нашла обработчик нажатия на кнопку, с проверкой полей на пустоту.
Переменная "btn" - для обработки нажатия "Отправить данные".
HTML:

```
<form><input type="submit" class="btn_submit disabled" value="Отправить данные" /></form>
```

JS:

```
btn = form.find('.btn_submit');
...
setInterval(function(){
            checkInput();
            var sizeEmpty = form.find('.empty_field').size();
            if(sizeEmpty > 0){
                if(btn.hasClass('disabled')){
                    return false
                } else {
                    btn.addClass('disabled')
                }
            } else {
                btn.removeClass('disabled')
            }
        },500);

        btn.click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('disabled')){
                lightEmpty();
                return false
            }else {
                form.submit();
            }
}
```

Хочу сделать то же самое, но при нажатии на ENTER.
Код выше не мой (что написано понимаю), как подстроить под себя? Я же не могу присвоить переменной нажатие на ENTER.

Вот мой обработчик:

```
$(table).keypress(function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode==13){проверка заполненного поля на пустоту}
}
```

Ссылка на источник, откуда был взят код: https://www.howtomake.com.ua/front/simple-check-form-field-jquery.html

Comment: Между прочем `.size()` вроде бы устарелый, наверное лучше использовать `.val().length`

Answer (score 0):

Может не совсем понимаю вопрос, но попробуйте для начала вот так:

```
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</form>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$('body').keypress(function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        var allFilled = true;
        var inputs = $('form input');
        for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if(inputs[i].value.length == 0) {
                var allFilled = false;
            }
        }
        if(allFilled == true) {
            $('form').submit();
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Если все поля формы заполнены, тогда при нажатии ЕНТЕР форма отправится. А если хоть одно поле не заполнено, тогда ничего не произойдет

Comment: Правила вопрос, добавлена ссылка на источник кода. Не понимаю что куда класть, все (весь код Jquery) в обработчик нажатия на ENTER?

Comment: только при нажатии на ENTER.

Comment: Нет, кнопка "btn_submit" не нужна.

Comment: А как же, например, класс 'empty_field', который Вы применили? Его тоже нужно добавить в код. Только выше обработчика событий? Или, нужно добавить весь код по работе с полями, но во внутрь добавить обработчик по нажатию на ENTER?